# Second Cyfer Quest wyrm hunting licence?

Tags: dragons-dogma

Stupidly sold the `Cyfer Quest Wyrm Hunt` licence, but now Maximillian won't talk to me in game because I don't have it. Is there any way to get a new one without starting over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the Black Cat merchant in Gran Soren